# How to use bash's complete or compgen -C (command) option?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When creating shell completion functionality in bash, it seems like the `-C` option would be powerful and common. It's defined like this:

> **-C** *command*
>
> *command*  is  executed in a subshell environment, and its
>   output is used as the possible completions.

That seems really straightforward. But, weirdly, it's not. If I do:

```
$ complete -C "echo one two three" test.sh
```

and then type `test.sh` and hit [tab] one time, I get that line filled out with

```
$ test.sh one two three test.sh  test.sh
```

back. What?! For comparison,

```
$ complete -W "one two three" test.sh
```

does exactly what I'd expect: it offers *one*, *three*, or *two* as possible completions (in sort order, of course).

I can't find any good documentation anywhere, so I'm experimenting.... maybe a semicolon helps? `complete -C "echo one two three;" test.sh` ... Ah, okay, this helps *some*, because it removes that weird `test.sh` from the end. But it still fills out the full string `one two three`. This is odd, because that description above definitely says "possible completions", plural. 
... so, hmmm, ah, newlines? Let's try `complete -C "echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree';" test.sh`.

Okay, so, this is promising. If I type `test.sh [tab]`, I get back `one    three  two`. But then, things go wrong. I add an `o` to resolve the ambiguity, so, `test.sh o[tab]`, and *that* returns

```
o      one    three  two
```

Which is puzzling. In fact, any string I type gets added to the list; if I do `test.sh wtf[tab]`, I get `one    three  two    wtf` echoed back. I guess possibly I need to do something sophisticated with `compgen`, but, again, I stress, this works as expected with `-W`. And, in fact

```
$ complete -W '$(echo one two three)' test.sh
```

works just fine (note single quotes to prevent premature expansion/execution, in case you do something more sophisticated than `echo` which could produce variable results).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12):

It's the job of the `-C` command to figure out what text to insert in response to a completion request. The interface is a bit strange:

- The argument to `-C` is interpreted as a bash script snippet. Bash appends three properly-quoted strings to this snippet:

  - the command whose arguments are being completed;
  - the prefix of the word where the cursor is, up to the cursor;
  - the word before the cursor.
- Some variables are added to the environment:

  - [`COMP_LINE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fLINE) contains the complete line in which completion is performed.
  - [`COMP_POINT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fPOINT) contains the cursor position inside `COMP_LINE` (counting from 0).
  - [`COMP_TYPE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fTYPE) is 9 for normal completion, 33 when listing alternatives on ambiguous completions, 37 for menu completion, 63 when tabbing between ambiguous completions, 64 to list completions after a partial completion.
  - [`COMP_KEY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fKEY) contains the key that triggered completion (e.g. a tab character if the user pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>).
- The output of the command is interpreted as text to replace the current word with. Note that this is a replacement, not a suffix to append; the command is supposed filter by the given prefix. It may contain multiple lines, in which case each line is considered a possible replacement.

This is roughly the same mechanism that is provided, and better [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion), for functions with `-F`. Functions get a somewhat saner interface: they can read the list of words of the current command in the [`COMP_WORDS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fWORDS) variable, and the starting position of the current word in [`COMP_CWORD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fCWORD); they write the results in the [`COMPREPLY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMPREPLY) array.

Since the useful arguments — in particular the prefix to complete — are passed at the end of the command, `-C` is pretty much only usable with an external command. Of course you can use something like `sh -c …`, but it won't be pretty.

```
complete -C 'sh -c '\'for x in one two three; do case $x in "$1"*) echo "$x";; esac''\'
```

Comment: Where did you find documentation about COMP_TYPE values?

Comment: @jarno In the manual (follow the link). What's not clear in the manual is that it gives _characters_ (TAB, `?`, etc.), but these characters need to be encoded as their ASCII number written in decimal (thus `9`, `63`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your completion functionality centralized inside the `complete` definition, without the hassle of external scripts and functions, the easiest way to use the `complete -C` option is to just define your handler function inside the command string. The `complete` builtin adds three strings directly after your command string when executing it, as *@Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'* pointed out in his answer:

1. the command whose arguments are being completed;
2. the prefix of the word where the cursor is, up to the cursor;
3. the word before the cursor.

For the example code of the original question we need only positional parameter `$2`, to `grep` the possible completions that have `$2` as prefix. The way to go would be:

```
    complete -C 'makelist() { echo one; echo two; echo three; }; filter() { makelist | grep "^$2" | sort -u; }; filter' test.sh
```

When entering `test.sh t<tab>`, `complete` will execute the command string with
a space and "test.sh", "t" and "test.sh" appended right after the last `filter`. That command will then:

- define the `makelist` function
- define the `filter` function
- call the `filter` function with the appended strings as parameters

  - `filter` will call `makelist`
  - `makelist` returns a list of all possible completions
  - `grep` the completions that match the prefix of the word where the cursor is, up to the cursor
  - uniquely `sort` these
  - pass them on back to `complete`