# Bash completions -C vs -F

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In the bash completion setup (https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) supplied by my system there seems to be an unequivocal preferences towards completing with `complete -F` as opposed to `complete -C`.

```
complete -p | grep -- -C # no match
```

The difference between the two appears to be that 
the `-F`unction-taking form expects a function that reads input from variables and outputs to variables wheres the `-C`ommand-taking form reads input from positional arguments and outputs to `stdout`.

I like the second approach better as it's more functional and the completions functions/programs are slightly easier to debug (as they don't depend on a particular context of variables).

However, https://github.com/scop/bash-completion's preference towards the former makes me wonder: are there any downsides to the `-C` approach apart from the obvious (negligible for a UI, IMHO) performance overhead of a new process?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250484/117549 if you haven't already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd consider `complete -C {command}` "more functional" than `complete -F {function}`, since the latter literally takes a function; so the motivation is not clear for your stated preference. But you're right, almost all examples and documentation show a preference for `complete ... -F {function} ...`, e.g., `complete -F _foobar foobar`, where the function `_foobar` is used to generate completion options for a hypothetical command `foobar`.

Main reasons are, presumably,

- the function "`_foobar`" can be used to complete multiple commands, e.g., perhaps a `foobar` package also has a `foo` and a `bar` command; `$1` is passed to the function so you know the name of the command being completed.
- the function variant seems to provide a lot more information to perform completions; the "`-C`" variant seems dumber by comparison (but, admittedly, I've always used the "`-F`" variant myself.)
- it's easier to set the completion options via the function (via the COMPREPLY array variable), than to rely on a command's output; the command runs in a subprocess so it's harder to pass info into it, and get info out of it.
- the  "-C command" variant spawns a subprocess, which, when pressing "tab-tab-tab" for completions, creates additional delays, when you really want this to feel instantaneous.
- the "-C command" variant would either have a long & complicated command in the `complete` statement, or it'd call an external shell script, in which case you'd have to ship and keep track of the location of that script (a pain).

Also, in my personal "completions", I have to get them working across older versions of bash and for various Unix's (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, Linux, BSD), and I've found a lot of variety in what is supported. Since "`complete`" returns `true` when it works, I use the following idiom which seems to be more portable across bash versions (I only included this here, since it shows the usage of "`-F {function} {commmand}`" is simpler/cleaner than a corresponding "`-C "command"`" would be):

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _cmd cmd 2>/dev/null \
|| complete             -o default -o nospace -F _cmd cmd 2>/dev/null \
|| complete             -o default            -F _cmd cmd 2>/dev/null \
|| complete                                   -F _cmd cmd
```

Likewise, if I have `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3` that all take basically the same completions (e.g., consider a completion script for `scp` and `ssh` that take a list of hostnames which you generate),

```
for c in cmd1 cmd2 cmd3; do
    # or that long complete statement shown above
    complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _cmd $c 2>/dev/null
done
```

For reference:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command

Comment: I stated many personal preferences/opinions here, but that's what the question is basically about. So, I welcome any supporting/contrasting opinions.

Comment: Thanks. I was exploring possibilities on how to do option parsing and autocompletion from simple declarative specs extractible from manpages. I ended up using the function form. Allowed me to reuse the generator functions from the bash-complete package. What I meant by more functional is that the -C form doesn't operate in a context -- all inputs are passed by copy. That's the spirit of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming .